# Signal to let connection open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, streaming

I'm currently wondering how tell my Rails app to not close a connection according to some data.

Let imagine I play a music, a very long one like 50 minutes. When I start playing this music, I also start to stream  (preload) the second one (without playing it). 
When my first music is at end, the second will fail at the end of what it was able to pre download because there were not any new bytes downloaded and the server will consider this request as fail (timeout).

Of course I don't want to increase the timeout. Everybody knows that to increase timeout may have more bad things than good.

I was wondering how send something like a `ping` to not consider this stream request as failed.

Here is my code Rails code:

```
send_data file.read,
          :status => status_code,
          :stream => 'true',
          :disposition =>  'inline'
```

Answer (score 0):

You reinventing the wheel. You need to `include ActionController::Live` to enable streaming in rails. This will solve your problem with timeout but you must to close all streams manually, remember that.

Here is example how to use that module:

```
class StreamingController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  def send_something
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    10.times {
      response.stream.write "This message will be repeated 10 times with delay in 1 second.\n"
      sleep 1
    }
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

[ActionController::Live documentation page](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html)

Also [SSE](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live/SSE.html) might be useful for you. Check it out too.